# Socket IO. Create Wav and send in response.

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, audio, socket.io

I create dynamically Wav file using this code in my node.js server:

```
Wav.prototype.getWavInt16Array = function(buffer){

var intBuffer = new Int16Array(buffer.length + 23), tmp;

intBuffer[0] = 0x4952; // "RI"
intBuffer[1] = 0x4646; // "FF"

intBuffer[2] = (2*buffer.length + 15) & 0x0000ffff; // RIFF size
intBuffer[3] = ((2*buffer.length + 15) & 0xffff0000) >> 16; // RIFF size

intBuffer[4] = 0x4157; // "WA"
intBuffer[5] = 0x4556; // "VE"

intBuffer[6] = 0x6d66; // "fm"
intBuffer[7] = 0x2074; // "t "

intBuffer[8] = 0x0012; // fmt chunksize: 18
intBuffer[9] = 0x0000; //

intBuffer[10] = 0x0001; // format tag : 1 
intBuffer[11] = this._channels; // channels: 2

intBuffer[12] = this._sampleRate & 0x0000ffff; // sample per sec
intBuffer[13] = (this._sampleRate & 0xffff0000) >> 16; // sample per sec

intBuffer[14] = (2*this._channels*this._sampleRate) & 0x0000ffff; // byte per sec
intBuffer[15] = ((2*this._channels*this._sampleRate) & 0xffff0000) >> 16; // byte per sec

intBuffer[16] = 0x0004; // block align
intBuffer[17] = 0x0010; // bit per sample
intBuffer[18] = 0x0000; // cb size
intBuffer[19] = 0x6164; // "da"
intBuffer[20] = 0x6174; // "ta"
intBuffer[21] = (2*buffer.length) & 0x0000ffff; // data size[byte]
intBuffer[22] = ((2*buffer.length) & 0xffff0000) >> 16; // data size[byte]  

for (var i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
    tmp = buffer[i];
    if (tmp >= 1) {
        intBuffer[i+23] = (1 << 15) - 1;
    }
    else if (tmp <= -1) {
        intBuffer[i+23] = -(1 << 15);
    }
    else {
        intBuffer[i+23] = Math.round(tmp * (1 << 15));
    }
}

return intBuffer;
};
```

How i can to send this wav to client side?
Can i create url link to wav and send just url? 
But i don't want to create any wav files on server.

Comment: You can make the client request a URL on the server that will respond by generating and sending this data, without writing it to any actual file. However, could you not generate it on the client with the Audio API instead? Why does you server have to do it?

Comment: (and there is no reason to use WebSockets here; plain HTTP will be fine)